# Tagging for the physical health and conditioning aspects of musicianship?

Tags: discussion, tags

As I'm sure we all know, health is an important part of being a musician. Pianists tend to be especially concerned with their hands, and singers tend to be concerned about everything located above the diaphragm.

- https://music.stackexchange.com/q/293/133
- [Pinky is raised uncontrollably when doing finger exercise](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/257/133)
- [How would you train for Chopin's Étude no. 2 op. 10?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/236/133)
- [Well-known composers or piano pieces generally suitable for someone with small hands?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/79/133)
- [How can I be sure that I am singing effortlessly in my natural voice?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/60/133)

Of course, this extends to guitarists, trombonists, what have you. This question: [How can I toughen up my fingertips?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/289/133) raised the topic of how these questions should be tagged.

[exercises](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises), [technique](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) and [fingering](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingering) both refer to different enough topics that I don't think they should apply here. The [hand](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand) tag might be useful for pianists specifically, but perhaps [health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) would be more inclusive? There could also be [conditioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning), which is a little different, and [body](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body), which might be too broad.

### Edit:

I like [health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) and [conditioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning) the best, but I think they could be a little more obvious to the community, like if they were instead [physical-health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-health) and [physical-conditioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-conditioning). That said, what's the official stance on combining consecutive tags like [physical](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical)[health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) and [physical](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical)[conditioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning)? That might be a good option, since it very easily categorizes everything as "physical" while still breaking out into "conditioning" and "health" in a way that would be easy for posters to use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really like [hand](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand).  It doesn't seem like it should be used for anything except questions actually discussing the hand -- improving hand strength, problems with hand pain, etc. -- but I don't think it's really useful in that case.  We're not likely to have a group of kinesiologists with music as a hobby following such a tag, and I think it would be enough to cover it with other tags and details in the question.

I think [exercises](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises) would be good for the hand strength question, and [health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) for the hand pain question.  They're more general and more related to the purpose of the question than purely the particular bit of anatomy involved.  I definitely think [body](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body) has the opposite problem, though, being way to broad.  It would be better to tag with the a more specific physical issue than just "body".

As for my question about toughening fingertips, I do like [conditioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning).  It's another "purpose" tag instead of a "this is the body part involved" tag, and thus more useful.  It's also a common term for the class of actions under consideration, and clear.  I've applied it to my question.

Comment: Another reason not to use `body` is because it refers to the body of an instrument.

Comment: Thinking about it, `exercises` could refer to playing an instrument and `conditioning` about maintaining an instrument. These might require a `finger-` prefix...

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of [physical](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical) because it covers all of the aforementioned tags.

However I can see that if you didn't know what it meant (e.g. from reading this meta question) you might struggle to see what was meant.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, but I think this might not be very obvious to users. I do like how it contrasts with the 'mental' side of music, though.

Comment: Doesn't `physical` become to broad then?