# Should there be a new tag for personal physical limitations?

Tags: discussion, tags

Example questions

- [Piano: Significantly right hand arrangement styles/composers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/significantly-right-hand-arrangements-for-piano)
- [Arthritis In Hands (Playing With Pain In Hands) - Are There Recommended Approaches?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/arthritis-in-hands-playing-with-pain-in-hands-are-there-recommended-approache)

Related meta questions: [Tagging for the physical health and conditioning aspects of musicianship?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/tagging-for-the-physical-health-and-conditioning-aspects-of-musicianship)

We could create an additional tag [physical-limitations](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-limitations)? I would like to know if there is a better word for this. (Perhaps one that does not get confused with the physical limitations of the instrument) (Also, I don't like requiring that it is called a "disability")

- Do you think this is a good idea?
- Any naming suggestions?

**Edit:** I tagged a few questions with this.

Comment: I'd be fine with this tag as proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tagged a few questions with this. Let me know if you have input.