# Tag to address disabilities/limitations other than physical

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are currently three MP&T questions regarding dyslexia. With the understanding that this is a small number, and I don't immediately find other questions regarding non-physical types of limitation (leaving aside [stage-fright](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stage-fright)), I suggest it's worthwhile to either rename the [physical-limitations](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-limitations) tag or add a new tag to encompass learning disabilities and other psychological/neuropsychological conditions or limitations.

As a discussion starting point, perhaps [limitation-or-disability](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limitation-or-disability).

Related question: [Should there be a new tag for personal physical limitations?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/should-there-be-a-new-tag-for-personal-physical-limitations)

---

**Update #1 (14 Jan 2021):** I've come across a couple of other posts related to students who for various cognitive reasons either cannot read music or have great difficulty. In light of @YourUncleBob's comments, I'm leaning toward two tags: [physical-limitations], which exists already, and [learning-disabilities], which would be new.

Would like more feedback on the subject before considering further action.

---

**Update #2 (26 Feb 2022):** Revisiting this question in light of [Dyslexia or Dyscalculia in Reading Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/121589/70803). A [learning-disabilities](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-disabilities) would fit the question, but I'm hoping for more feedback before creating a new tag and then adding it to relevant questions.

Comment: Dyslexia is a neurological condition, not a psychological problem like stage fright, therefor the physical-limitations tag is not inappropriate.

Comment: @YourUncleBob Appreciate the comment. Do you think a new [tag:limitation-or-disability] tag would be suitable to encompass both physical limitations and neurological ones like dyslexia?

Comment: Yes, but the current "physical-limitations" tag does that too. The real question is whether we should lump physical and psychological hurdles together in a broad "limitation-or-disability" tag. They require very different expertise. I can see value in keeping the "physical-limitations" tag and maybe creating a separate one like "psychological-hurdles" or "performance-psychology" or simply "psychology".

Comment: @YourUncleBob FYI: I've updated the post and would appreciate your thoughts and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think [learning-disabilities](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-disabilities) would be a worthwhile tag based on current questions asked as we've had a decent amount of question in this vein. I do think it should always be paired with a subtopic like [teaching](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching), [learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), [practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) as a question with that tag alone may not make sense for a site.