# Tag for pain/ergonomics?

Tags: discussion, tags

Related: [Tagging for the physical health and conditioning aspects of musicianship?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/47/6556)

It’s common to experience pain when learning a new instrument or technique, and I see a lot of questions on the subject. I’ve asked a couple myself, for [piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20220/right-hand-wrist-forearm-soreness) and [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17519/fingertip-care-for-guitarists). Sometimes, pain means you’re doing something wrong, and sometimes it means you’re learning to do something right.

Between this and NReilingh’s earlier question, I think we should have one or two tags related to pain/injury and conditioning/ergonomics, but I’m not sure what the best tag names or synonyms would be here.

Comment: Wow, that question was from a while ago! I think `health` could easily apply to pain/injury questions, but I agree we should have a separate tag for the conditioning and physical training aspects.

Comment: So something like `health` and `conditioning` then? I’m really not sure what’s a good fit here or whether we should bring forth the answers to the previous question. Post an answer I guess so that we can vote on it?

Answer (score 2):

I see that [health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) already exists, and it should be a good fit for [pain](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pain) and [injury](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury) questions, so I recommend making those synonyms of [health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health).

Meanwhile, [conditioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning) does not already exist, and I suggest creating it according to the weak consensus on the earlier question and the comments above.

I also recommend [ergononomics](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergononomics) as a synonym of [health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) or [posture](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posture).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the [technique](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique), [posture](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posture), or similar tag for such questions, because you're not really asking about the pain (if you are, go take an aspirin), but whatever technique or posture that's causing you pain.