# Suggesting tags for care of various body parts

Tags: support, tags

Related: [Tag for pain/ergonomics?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/811/19678)

Inspired by [Should drummers have blisters/calluses on their hands?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/50398/19678), I would like to propose the following tags:

- care of hands
- care of voice
- ergonomics
- care of the mouth and tongue

There are tags for care and maintenance of equipment.  But for most musicians, care of the various body parts involved in producing the desired sound is very important.

This isn't just about maintaining good health.  It's also about how to care for the body parts you use intensively when you play, to get optimal results.

I believe I once asked a question about braces and choice of wind instrument, and this could also be tagged *care of the mouth*.

*Ergonomics* is a bit different from how you care for your specific body part.  It's about how the different body parts work together.  It's a lovely succinct word that says a lot.

(I suppose I have enough rep to just create some tags myself, but when I have done that on other sites where I had a lot more rep, I found that it's better to open up a discussion before just creating a tag.)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the tag we discussed previously (mallet-percussion) I can't see any use for these. We have a [health](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) tag already, and based on the site scope we are very unlikely to need anything that granular.

Tags should be created when there is actually a need for them, and they are used for future visitors to find classes of questions. Your suggestions will not best serve those future visitors.

Comment: if you need we can discuss this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67748/discussion-on-answer-by-dr-mayhem-suggesting-tags-for-care-of-various-body-parts).

Comment: This question has made me wonder if there's a possible concern about health questions similar to legal questions. I.e., this is not a health (law) related Stack and while some of us may know about health (law) as it pertains to music, giving advice on such an important topic could create risk for the asker and SE.